# Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:jaxb2-maven-plugin:1.6:xjc

Tags: java, maven, jaxb, java-17

I am in the process of migrating my project from Java 1.8 to Java 17. However, when I attempt to execute 'mvn clean install,' it fails with the following error:

> Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:jaxb2-maven-plugin:1.6:xjc
> (InternalAPI) on project ProjectName: Execution InternalAPI of goal
> org.codehaus.mojo:jaxb2-maven-plugin:1.6:xjc failed: A required class
> was missing while executing
> org.codehaus.mojo:jaxb2-maven-plugin:1.6:xjc:
> javax/activation/DataSource

below is the plugin used to generate

```
 <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>InternalAPI</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>xjc</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <schemaDirectory>../project/src/main/resources/xsd/int</schemaDirectory>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/target/generated-sources</outputDirectory>
                            <bindingFiles>binding.xml</bindingFiles>
                            <packageName>com.xyz.schema</packageName>
                            <clearOutputDir>true</clearOutputDir>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>PublicAPI</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>xjc</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <schemaDirectoryrectory>../project/src/main/resources/xsd/pub</schemaDirectoryrectory>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/target/generated-sources</outputDirectory>
                            <bindingFiles>binding.xml</bindingFiles>
                            <packageName>com.xyz.schema.api</packageName>
                            <clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

With Java17 is something change with the version? With latest version of Jaxb2 also its not working.